# Server-side Responsive Web Design

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, responsive-design

I've been researching [**Responsive Web Design**](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design) lately.  While there are many techniques and practices that fall under the umbrella of "Responsive Web Design", essentially the main pillar of RWD seems to be CSS3 `media` queries.  So, RWD is basically a client side strategy.

But with low-resolution layouts, you often have to simply *remove* entire sections of HTML.  For example, a 3 column layout may need to become a 1 or 2 column layout on lower resolutions, meaning that you're basically hiding entire `DIV`s at lower resolutions.  The problem I see here is that you still need to actually SEND the same amount of HTML code to a low-res device, even though it will never be displayed.  In other words, you're sending the same 3-columns worth of HTML to a hi-res screen and a low-res mobile phone, but it's really a complete waste of bandwidth every time you send it to the low-res mobile phone.

**Question:** Am I correct in my understanding here, or does RWD also incorporate *server-side* techniques?

For example, suppose you have a skeletal HTML page like:

```
<div id = "main-content">
  <!-- content goes here -->
</div>
```

And `onload` (or `onresize`), the client browser detects the screen resolution and makes an AJAX request that fills in `main-content` with the appropriate HTML for that resolution.

Are techniques like this that utilize server-side strategies to implement RWD ever used in practice?

Comment: "For example, a 3 column layout may need to become a 1 or 2 column layout on lower resolutions, meaning that you're basically hiding entire DIVs at lower resolutions" — Usually that means that you apply different CSS so that the three blocks appear one after the other instead of side by side.

Comment: The 3 column layout would be floated, once the media query fires for a mobile state the floated divs would be set to block and the floats would be removed.  RWD relies on designing for mobile first.  Not all websites lend themselves to a pure RWD solution.  It all "depends"

Comment: For most sites, the amount of bandwidth you would save by serving a different file to different devices would be very minimal. If a site is designed well, it should only take maybe 100 or 200 lines at most for the CSS media queries.

Comment: Text content has a considerably smaller footprint than image content.  If you have so much content that its actually worth making the document smaller, you just might have too much content on a single page.  This is a bad thing for *all* devices, not just small ones.

Answer (score 3):

In general, responsive development - if done correctly - should not have any redundant or repeated data in the markup.  Likewise, content displayed at one screen width will also be displayed at another width, just in a different way.

I love the idea of making an AJAX call based on screen dimensions at page-load, but that's not really the idea of responsive design, and would actually take longer for the page to load (for the visitor)..  It would also mean that the page layout wouldn't adapt when the browser window dimensions are changed (for example: switching orientation on a tablet).  Unless you propose a new AJAX call at that point, in which case you'll be sending a lot more traffic than a single responsive page-load, and putting more load on your server too.

Comment: Not to mention that `onresize` fires once for every single change in dimensions. In other words, if you go from 1000x1000 to 950x1000, it'll fire 50 times - 50 AJAX calls.

Comment: @Sébastien Renauld, that's a good point, but the client-side logic could always avoid the AJAX call unless the resolution change will actually trigger a layout change.

Comment: @Channel72: you're then introducing either a `setTimeout` to buffer the calls, or layout hardcoding in JS. The first introduces UI latency, which users hate. The second introduces an unnecessary dependency which can easily be covered by media queries.

Answer (score 2):

You pretty much answer your on question...

The time you will need to make a ajax call when the window is resized is much more longer then just give the whole html page once and use css instead.

And the main idea of responsive design is not hide your content. When you hide your content, you got a lot of troubles, like search engines that will show up your content but when a guy visit your website on his tablet the content doesn't show up.

**Edit:**

Just to make clear when I talk about content, I am talking about what is important on your page stuffs like a "adsense" or other things that doesn't really matter to the visitor should be hide at no problem at all.

About server-side technique there is a bunch out there, one good example is [Adaptive Images](http://adaptive-images.com/) that send images on lower resolution to lower devices, but you can do that with client side technique too.

**Edit2:**

I almost forgot that

> Not to mention that onresize fires once for every single change in dimensions. In other words, if you go from 1000x1000 to 950x1000, it'll fire 50 times - 50 AJAX calls. @Sébastien Renauld

Comment: +1, I'd like to add it's okay to hide images and such non-textual stuff, and it's often the best approach

Comment: Looks like my comment is flying around ^_^

Comment: @Shomz I hope you're not implying that `display: none` is ok to use for the purpose of hiding images from a small device.  Hidden or not, the user is still downloading the images.  Hiding it via server side is fine, but you have to ask yourself if the image really has a place in your document at all.  Either the content in the image is valuable or its not.  If its purely decorative, it can be more effectively hidden on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you hide additional columns on mobile? Removing information is never a good idea, that'll only make visitors dislike the mobile version of your site.

Columns on a web site are usually created with floated html elements. Remove said floats with a media query and voila! The information is now all in one column.

If that one column ends up being far too tall you may want to consider adding toggles for showing/hiding the information, but that's as far as I'd go about removing content for mobile sites.

Comment: In his "Mobile Best Practices" W3C recommends to not show all contents to make the page lighter, I think. I refer the [5.3 Page Layout and Content](http://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-bp/#bpgroupplayout) and [5.3.4 Navigation Bars etc. (Extraneous material)](http://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-bp/#cm)

Answer (score 0):

http://css-tricks.com/make-client-side-data-available-server-side/

In this article Chris Coyier talks about using clientside methods to check the current width of the screen, then save it to a cookie for use server side - then refresh the page.  I don't entirely approve of the method, but perhaps it could be useful to you.

You may want to look into JavaScript feature detection or even UA sniffing, though its frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to remove/hide columns in lower resolutions. The trick would be to stack then underneath each other in low res, then align them in columns in higher res. For example:

```
<div class="one">Column One</div>
<div class="two">Column Two</div>
<div class="three">Column Three</div>

.one, .two, .three {
blah blah blah, whatever needs to be here.
}
```

then add CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
float: left; /* screens larger than 600px wide will throw them into columns via float*/
}
```